# Which fishes produce alarm signals to warn other group members about in coming predators

Tags: zoology, ichthyology

Atlantic Goliath Groupers are fishes which produce unique low frequency sounds to mate and when approached by predatory fish . The sounds produced when approached by a predator (or even a scuba diver) are different from those produced whilst mating.

The problem is this fish is found only in the Atlantic.  I'm specifically looking for fishes in the Indian ocean . Thank you for ur time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some fishes produce alarm signals as sounds.

members of family Pamadasyidae-the grunts.

the family scaridae e.g.—Parrot fish.[image]

sea catfish Galeichthyes felis[image]

gafftopsail catfish[image]

Indian loach[image]

Trigger fish[image]

Epinephelus striatus[image]

For mor information see the link. http://www.fishfarmingtechniques.com/fish-structure/specialized-organs/sound-producing-organs/sound-producing-organs-in-fishes-specialized-organs-fisheries/13563